# An Exercise on parallel programming and object oriented design

Tags: oop, parallel-processing

I am trying to self-study both object oriented design and parallel programming using the following books:

- "agile software development" by Robert C. Martin
- Bruce Eckel's "Thinking in Patterns with Java"
- "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming" Maurice Herlihy
- "Programming Massively Parallel Processors" by David B. Kirk

But to practice I need to work on some project. Can you please help me finding a project where I can practice both these skills. I am looking for a project which involves both working with design patterns (and basic OOP principles) but also some heavy parallelizable algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a server is a good real-world test of parallel programming skills.

Comment: I think you're confusing parallelism and concurrency.

Comment: I suppose I might be, but if OP is fairly green to the whole subject area, it's still a good introduction to dealing with issues such as shared state and the like.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://insidethecpu.com/2015/01/23/object-oriented-test-driven-design-in-c-and-java/) is a step-by-step tutorial on the subject.